# Running turf.js on desktop?

Tags: turf, node-js

Morgan Herlocker answered in another question, that he uses `turf.js` on his desktop with `node.js`.

I'm really new to GIS and won't become pro for all hacks. My need is:

1. having a geojson with a polygon - I got it
2. add a buffer of 5km to that geojson-plygon - well, my problem
3. having again a geojson with only the buffer - the result from 2
4. add the geojson-buffer to a OpenStreetMap - I got it

I only use buffer and all  operations are the same every time. That is why I do not have to step in deep.

This is what happens after the script-way:

[image]

It remains a problem of `epsg:3857` or `epsg:4326`

The result is imported to OpenStreetMap.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your enviornment. If you want to add the GeoJSON buffer to  a OpenStreetmap, where is this running? Isn't this running in a browser?

Comment: And secondly, how much Node do you know? The way to install it in node is to type `npm install turf` Does that require more expansion?

Comment: I can use a tool from the swiss OSM community to import a geojson-file and having a map back. And Node? No knowledge, I just read about it in the other question... As I understand, I can setup node. Then I can somewhere type your stuff somewhere? So, to be successfull, I need first to install Node - right?

Comment: Yes, You'll have to first install node, and then install turf by the command I had given in my previous comment. But you'll still have to call the code from there in some way. How do you plan to do that? will you write code for that?

Answer (score 7):

Since you are a beginner at Node, I'll try to give you a step by step answer

1. Firstly you need to install Node on your system. The exact steps will depend on your Operating system, and version, but it's a good bet that you will find the installer at https://nodejs.org/download/
   You should also note that if you have an updated installer, then NPM or the Node Package Manager will also be installed for you.
2. Now you need to install turf on your system. The Node way of doing this, is to create a folder, and then install the library inside that folder, so that you can work inside that folder. 
   Open the Node.js command prompt (if you are on windows), and go to your working directory. Then type `npm install turf`. This command will download the required files (turf as well as dependencies) from the internet, and install it your working directory.
3. Now that you have installed the library, you will want to use it. Generally speaking, Node modules & libraries do not have any UI of their own. You call them in your own Nodejs scripts.

You want to buffer and get the buffered output as GeoJSON. Here is an example script that buffers a polygon, and writes the output as a GeoJSON file

```
//Import the required modules
var turf = require( "turf" );
var fs = require('fs');

//input GeoJSON Feature
var mumbai={"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[72.7752778054935,19.2690995044639],[72.7817405956684,19.1238719055124],[72.8102749851638,19.1265959946878],[72.8247751057141,19.0910359643985],[72.8153720376396,19.0437583107182],[72.8209940779221,19.0352490234709],[72.8329105061117,19.0434886443927],[72.8359963318184,19.0373312064806],[72.8231900924928,19.0205055493087],[72.8125475128558,19.029908429424],[72.8080633067106,18.9898352623244],[72.7870845004595,18.947660113865],[72.7942309393155,18.937263881405],[72.809080960536,18.9503035811928],[72.8217391510222,18.9394947874404],[72.799135569344,18.9068306279723],[72.8113769649099,18.8893472433276],[72.8218126386322,18.8951870964281],[72.8474780411575,18.9235963464463],[72.8675088075429,19.0019646776918],[72.8819781251631,19.0064190047499],[72.8877097499884,18.9888559741936],[72.9236539940438,18.9983155390154],[72.9660988576404,19.0502455556637],[72.9836291475658,19.1747956918978],[72.9248922078066,19.2203564322991],[72.8998650805814,19.2558042171924],[72.8514714066599,19.2738226789422],[72.8514714066599,19.2738226789422],[72.8514714066599,19.2738226789422],[72.7752778054935,19.2690995044639]]]},"properties":{}};

//Buffer it by 500 meters
var buffered = turf.buffer(mumbai, 500, 'meters');

//try writing to a file
fs.writeFile("D:/buffered.geojson", JSON.stringify(buffered), function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
}); 

//also display on Console
console.log("The Output Generated was: ");
console.log(buffered);
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds great and I can follow so far! What I need is to read a geojson as well. But I can try it by myself. With this version, I have only to rename the filename and thats it. Great!

Comment: it worked! But the output has a problem with epsg:3857 or epsg:4326. When I use the json in openstreetmap, it looks ugly, see first post. How can I set the proper geosystem (or whatever)?

Comment: The output will be in the same projection as your input. And I don't see any issue with the buffer. It should look like that. What were you expecting?

Comment: I think you are expecting a eucliedian buffer while Turf is giving you a Geodesic buffer, which is more correct. Please see this article on ESRI's sites which explains the issue in detail: http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0111/geodesic.html